# Unable to download Azure artifacts on Ubuntu ARM machine

Tags: command-line, 22.04, arm

We are experiencing problems while downloading artifacts in Ubuntu ARM64 instances and are receiving an error message-

```
Failed to parse structured output from Universal Packages tooling (ArtifactTool)
Exception: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

azext_devops.devops_sdk.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: No release could be found based on the provided information.
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.exception_handler: handling generic error
cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Traceback (most recent call last)
```

After investigating the logs, found the below error and did some research on them. As per the observation-

```
• cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Failed to update Universal Packages tooling.

• No release could be found based on the provided information.
```

It appears that this is a bug issue, and there is no way to download packages from Azure Artifacts because artifactool does not exist for ARM architectures.

Can we get help on this?

Comment: If ARM64 is not support by Azure Artefacts there is hardly any help possible. Best option would be to contact Microsoft and ask about the status of ARM64 support.